# Entering Germany after 3 months (having a residence permit) of absense and having received a UK's residence permit

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, resident-permit, legal

I'm not an EU citizen.

The situation is:

I lived in Germany for 3 years, still registered there and have a bank account. 
I have a German residence permit (niederlassungserlaubnis) received after a Blue Card.

I got a job in the UK, went there and received UK's residence permit.
I wasn't sure if I want to stay in the UK and now I want to go back to Germany.

Am I eligible to go back to Germany bearing in mind that I was absent in Germany less than 6 months?

The law seems to be rather vague and it is specified that if intentions of staying abroad are not permanent then you may be able to return.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, §51(7) states that when a foreigner does **not** return within a period of 6 months or a longer period stipulated by the foreigner authorities, the granted residence title will be invalidated (erlischt).

So either return within 6 months or get an extension granted (in writing) to clear up your affairs in the UK.

§51(6) does indeed imply that, but returning within a (nowadays) normal probation time and the fact that you retained your residence and account should be valid arguments against this vague paragraph, whereas §51(7) is very clear.

(Just don't tell the registry authorities that you left without 'saying goodbye'... )